# How to share (or synchronize) a switch signal to several devices with a stronger current?

Tags: switches

I have a 230 Vac current (max 5 A), which is in "on/off" state, but I need it to propagate to several devices (e.g. 6), which can go up to 1500-1700 W (total), 230 Vac.

In other words, the devices are fed from another source (which allows 1700 W 230 Vac), but I need them to be switched on/off current synchronously with the other 230 Vac current.

In a nutshell, I need to make a big switch (8 A) out of a smaller (5 A) switch.

How can I share or synchronize the switch to those devices?

Comment: It's not clear what  you mean by "propagate". It's not an engineering term. Please explain Also if you only have 230V at 5A (1150 W) available, how do you expect to power devices that may draw up to 1700W?

Comment: It sounds like you want a relay or contactor. These use a small current to activate an electromagnet that operates a switch to control larger currents. Relays and contactors are conceptually the same, but the term ‘contactor’ usually refers to a high current relay. You would require a relay with a 230VAC coil and  spst contacts for 10A or so. These can be sourced from electrical wholesalers and other specialist suppliers. One example might be an Omron G2R series with plug in base.

Comment: Google [automatic vacuum control switch](https://www.google.com/search?q=automatic+vacuum+control+switch) - maybe that's the kind of thing you're looking for.

Comment: @Kartman you want to post as an answer as your comment is rather complete

Comment: @Soleil those kind of control switches look at the current drawn by the 'small device' and switch the 'large device(s)' on or off. So after you plug them all in, when you turn on the 'small device', the control switch sees that it has been turned on and so it then supplies power to the 'large device(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a relay that operates from the 230V 5A supply and switches the loads on the 8A supply

An example part would be
Finder Relays inc model 46.52.8.230.0054

[image]

A DIN-rail socket is available if you want to use this in an electrical panel.

Comment: For AC, should't I use a bipole switch rather than an unipole ?

Comment: Depends on the local electrical standards and your specific application. Normally you would only switch the active wire.